# Pegando vários campos de uma coluna em mysql e dividindo em arrays

Tags: php

Tenho um campo mysql chamado descrião, o mesmo armazena arrays separados por '|'.
formando um grupo.

Quando tenho mais de um grupo acrescento um * ao final para dizer que é um novo grupo.

2|Sacolas com acabamento  dourado |1|16,80|16.80 * 8|teste sacolas 2 |3|9|27.00

Preciso separar e mostrar da seguinte forma:

2  Sacolas com acabamento dourado  1  16,80  16,80
8  teste Sacolas                   3  9      27,00

Assim preenchendo estes campos
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

havendo no banco de dados 3..4..8 linhas ele deve preencher estas linhas.

exemplo:
2  Sacolas com acabamento dourado  1  16,80  16,80

```html
<?php
foreach($oss_list as $cat_edit){
    $descricao= $cat_edit['descricao'];
    $campos = explode('|', $descricao);
    $array = [];
    
    //pega o total de linhas
    $totaldelinhas = substr_count($descricao, '*');
    $ir = 0;
    while ($ir < $totaldelinhas) {
        echo $tt = explode("|",$descricao);
?>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control cod" id="cod" name="cod[]" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control desc" id="desc" name="desc[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="qnd" name="qnd[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="vlund" name="vlund[]" onblur="calcular()"></td>
    <!-- todos os inputs com style="display: none; são para uso nos calculos-->
    <td><input style="display: none;" type="text" class="form-control soma" id="vltotal" name="vltotal[]" onblur="calcular()">
        <input type="text" class="form-control somaS" id="vltotalS"></td>
</tr>
<?php
        $ir++;
    }
}
?>
```

8  teste Sacolas                   3  9      27,00
4  teste Sacolas 4                 4  7      23,00

como faço isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente dessa forma:

```
<?php 
    foreach($oss_list as $cat_edit){ 
        $descricao = explode('|', $cat_edit['descricao']);
?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control cod" id="cod" name="cod[]" value="<?php echo $descricao[0]; ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control desc" id="desc" name="desc[]" value="<?php echo $descricao[1]; ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="qnd" name="qnd[]" value="<?php echo $descricao["2"]; ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="vlund" name="vlund[]" value="<?php echo $descricao[3]; ?>"></td>
        <!-- todos os inputs com style="display: none; são para uso nos calculos-->
        <td><input style="display: none;" type="text" class="form-control soma" id="vltotal" name="vltotal[]" onblur="calcular()">
            <input type="text" class="form-control somaS" id="vltotalS"></td>
    </tr>    
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Ele criou 3 linhas de input ( era 2 pois tenho dois grupos de resultados e preencheu somente a primeira

Comment: @RichardBarcelos conseguiu acertar?

Comment: Olá Amigo, eu mudei  o script, antes de cadastrar tudo no banco na mesma coluna eu criei uma tabela para a descrição somente..

depois dei um foreach antes do <tr> povoando os campos. ficou beleza, obrigado pelo apoio.

Comment: Perfeito, se puder aceitar minha resposta... se lhe ajudou, grato.